# Trying to add instance as a Node element to div

Tags: javascript, html

JS newbie here.

Hi, I am trying to add an instance as a Node to a div element I created,
but it gives this error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Should I not do it this way? is this wrong?

I want to create div element for every GitHub user I am searching for, adding 3 tags for each under a div.

I thought doing so by building a class with methods will help with DRY.

```
class AddElement {
  constructor(name, tag) {
    this.name = name;
    this.tag = tag;
  }

  elem() {
    this.name = document.createElement(this.tag);
    document.body.append(this.name);
  }

  elemProp(property) {
    this.elem();
    this.name.innerHTML = property;
  }

  elemError() {
    this.elem();
    this.name.innerHTML = this.name + ' does not exist.';
    this.name.style.color = 'red';
  }

  elemImg(property) {
    this.elem();
    this.name.src = property;
    this.name.height = 150;
  }
}

async function getJson(name) {

  let response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${name}`);
  
  if (response.status === 404) {
    new AddElement('notFound', 'h3').elemError();
    throw new Error('User not found!');
  } else {
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
}

async function gitUserInfo(name) {

  let jsonData = await getJson(name);

  let img = jsonData.avatar_url;
  let login = jsonData.login;
  let bio = jsonData.bio;

  let arr = [
    new AddElement('userimg', 'img').elemImg(img),
    new AddElement('login', 'h2').elemProp(login),
    new AddElement('bio', 'h3').elemProp(bio),
  ]
  
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.append(div);
    arr.forEach(item => div.appendChild(item))
}

let search = document.getElementById('searchUser');
search.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      gitUserInfo(search.value)
    } else if (search.value === '') {
      removeTag('h2');
      removeTag('h3');
      removeTag('img');
    }
});

function removeTag(tag) {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName.length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[i].remove();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating an array of `htmlElement`'s but an array of `AddElements`.

However you were getting the exception as you were creating an array of undefined objects because you were calling the ctor and then some properties that had no `return` statement so `arr` looked like this:

```
 arr[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]
```

It is bad practice to initialize an array in this manner.  Initialize your objects first, apply the jsonData, THEN add them to the array.  OR simply bypass the array and just modify the dom as you go.

Also, inside `elem()` you are modifying the dom by adding a newly created element to `<body>` before you've processed the data. If it were to work as you have it written you would be appending these objects twice.

In the code below I've stripped out the async function and just created a hard-coded json object for brevity.

Also, elements created by `document.createElement()` contain all the properties you need so there is no reason to create your own.

```js
class AddElement {
  constructor(name, tag) {
    this.obj = document.createElement(tag);
    this.obj.name = name;
  }

  elemProp(txt) {
    this.obj.innerHTML = txt;
    return this.obj;
  }

  elemImg(imgUrl) {
    this.obj.src = imgUrl;
    this.obj.height = 150;
    return this.obj;
  }
}

let jsonData = {
  avatar_url: "https://picsum.photos/200",
  login: "somelogin",
  bio: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
}

function gitUserInfo(data) {
  let arr = [
    new AddElement('userimg', 'img').elemImg(data.avatar_url),
    new AddElement('login', 'h2').elemProp(data.login),
    new AddElement('bio', 'h3').elemProp(data.bio),
  ]

  let div = document.createElement('div');

  arr.forEach(item => div.appendChild(item));

  document.body.append(div);

}

gitUserInfo(jsonData)
```